# program to implement password security in c languge?

Tags: c++, c

Any idea how to get like this feature in c or c++

password= ****************

but at the end system gets right password(means real input) but other people see this.

Comment: Is it console program or with GUI?

Comment: @Pradeep its a console program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm the password of a user, use [pam](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam) (the [official page](http://kernel.org/linux/libs/pam/) is hosted on kernel.org and therefore down as of writing), in particular [`pam_authenticate`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_authenticate).

If your application has its own authentication architecture (and most of the time, it shouldn't), execute `stty -echo`, ask for the password, and then execute `stty echo` to restore the original behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the terminal that it *suppresses the echo* during the input. Maybe your operating system already provides a function that reads a password from the terminal. It might be called `getpassword` or `getpass` or `getpasswd`.

See the command `stty` to get an overview of the terminal options.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing without using library, you can use getch to get pressed character and print * for any character got from getch and use any key for for escape (here I use Enter).

Sample code

```
  while(true) {
       ch = getch();
     if(ch== 13)   // ASCII Code for Enter Key 
         break;
     cout<<"*";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

turn off echo

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/12256/

windows

```
#include <windows.h>

void echo( bool on = true )
  {
  DWORD  mode;
  HANDLE hConIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  GetConsoleMode( hConIn, &mode );
  mode = on
       ? (mode |   ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT )
       : (mode & ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));
  SetConsoleMode( hConIn, mode );
  }
```

posix

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void echo( bool on = true )
  {
  struct termios settings;
  tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &settings );
  settings.c_lflag = on
                   ? (settings.c_lflag |   ECHO )
                   : (settings.c_lflag & ~(ECHO));
  tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &settings );
  }
```